# Trying to use Naxam.Mapbox.iOS show blank page with Mapbox icon but no map

Tags: ios, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, mapbox

I've been trying to get the example going for Naxam.Mapbox.iOS as described here: https://blogs.naxam.net/using-mapbox-in-xamarin-ios-ffa9bdee13f4

I'm using Visual Studio/Xamarin 8.6.5 on my MacBook Pro with MacOS Catalina 10.15.4. I added NuGet Packages Naxam.Mapbox.iOS 5.4.0 and Xamarin.Essentials 1.5.3.2 to my project. I created an account at Mapbox.com and an access token for me to use in the project which I added as the MGLAccountManager.AccessToken property to the Info.plist file. The project has been created using the iOS Single View App template. Finally I added the --registrar:static argument to the Additional mtouch arguments in my iOS Build.

I added the first snippet of the blog post to my project as follows:

```
namespace MapboxSingleView
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            var map = new MGLMapView(View.Bounds, new NSUrl("mapbox://styles/naxamtest/cj5kin5x21li42soxdx3mb1yt"));
            View.AddSubview(map);
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to run this in my simulator using Debug -> iPhone 11 iOS 13.5 shows a blank/white page with just the Mapbox logo in the bottom left corner but no actual map being displayed at all.

Trying without the NSUrl or adding the map's center & zoom level snippet as described doesn't help either. I tried contacting Naxam, but so far haven't received any response from them.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

The fact you can see the Mapbox logo indicates that you have done the installation correctly. The blank white page is usually down to a problem with the access token. You say you added

```
MGLAccountManager.AccessToken
```

to your info.plist file. The gif in the link on the tutorial page shows that if you are adding the entry in the info.plist file, then you should just add:

```
MGLAccountManager (with a value of <Your Mapbox access token>)
```

to that file. If you wish, instead, to add the access code *in your code*, then use:

```
MGLAccountManager.AccessToken = "<Your Mapbox access token>"
```

So it changes depending on if you want to enter your code in the info.plist file or as a line in your own code.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I did add the value of my access token to Info.plist file. If I cat that file I see this snippet:

`        ...
 <key>MGLAccountManager.AccessToken</key>
 <string>pk.xxx</string>
</dict>
</plist>`

Is this not in the correct spot in the Info.plist file?

(I masked the access token with x's evidently.)

Comment: In the info.plist file your key should be `MGLAccountManager` not `MGLAccountManager.AccessToken` just as it is shown in the gif.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I'm still seeing the same blank/white page using `<key>MGLAccountManager</key>` using either my created access token or the default public access token.

I think I'm starting to get confused. Mapbox (https://www.mapbox.com/install/ios/download-permission/) shows `MGLMapboxAccessToken` instead of `MGLAccountManager`, but trying that doesn't help either.

Comment: I tried to switch to an Android solution just to see if I can get something going there and again going by Naxam's example (https://blogs.naxam.net/using-mapbox-in-xamarin-android-7ffe2466f5f7). I downloaded quite a few NuGet packages, but the mentioned MapboxAccountManager is nowhere to be found.